# Why in the console I receive a certain message or warning?

Tags: java

Do you have any idea what is the reason that I receive this message:

> Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.openxml4j

Something to do with the repository or something else?

Comment: It looks like they included this sentence to show in the console output when things go wrong in a general way. You can ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a warning produced by Java 9 (and later) JVMs when some application or library code does something that is breaking the new (Java 9+) modularity rules by accessing Java internal classes, etcetera.  Other messages will briefly explain what the problem is.

The reason for the warning is that a future version of Java is likely to forbid what the application / library is doing.  So, they (the Java team) are suggesting that you tell / remind the people who developed the "offending" code that they need to fix it ... if they want their code to still work.

What can you do?

1. Report the problem to the developers.
2. Upgrade to a newer versions of the app or library which have fixed the problem.
3. Grit your teeth and put up with the warning messages.
4. Use `--add-opens` options to suppress the messages on a case by case basis.  (But note that the warnings are liable to turn into hard errors in a later version!)

For more information, read about the `--add-opens` and `--illegal-access` options in the [Java 9 `java` manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm).